# How long does it take to execute a DoS attack on a PC using the ping... -t CMD command?

Tags: denial-of-service

Suppose the target of a Denial of Service attack is a PC on LAN with IP 192.168.1.10. Then, I can continue to ping the target by running the ping command in an infinite loop in CMD, that is, by executing the command `ping 192.168.1.10 -t`.

How long would such a ping flood take to successfully crash the target PC, assuming it to be an average home PC?

Comment: Assuming you are using another average home PC, it won't suffer from the DDOS.

Comment: Tiny ICMP packets every second will not affect the target at all. You have not described a "ping flood".

Comment: You will end up eating all your memory running `cmd` before DoSing the other computer. You will execute a self inflicted DoS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To put some hard numbers on it: it'll take forever.

`ping -t` means "send one 'ICMP echo request' packet of 60 total bytes every second".  Counting the 60-byte response, this works out to a bandwidth usage of 960 bits per second.

You'll be able to DoS someone using a 1200 bps modem.  You'll have a noticeable impact on anything less than a 9600 bps modem.  Against a modern DSL or cable modem, or a gigabit ethernet connection, your "attack" will consume less bandwidth than the routine housekeeping traffic.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer : It won't.

Long answer : It can't because there is not enough data being sent to overload the network connection. Considering a lot of PCs have gigabit network cards, flooding a pc with ping requests only sends a few bytes at a time. It wouldn't even be considered a Denial of service attack (DoS)

You would need something like a distributed denial of service attack which utilises many machines which all target 1 particular victim. Better still, an Amplified Distributed denial of service attack using NTP (Network Time Protocol) might do it.

these are considered amplified (or reflected) as you spoof a request which sends a few bytes to a time server, mimicking your intended victim as the source of the request , and it returns many many more bytes to your intended target as a response. Do it to many time servers at once, and you most likely can crash (or at least overload) network connectivity of your intended victim.

See here :

https://blog.cloudflare.com/technical-details-behind-a-400gbps-ntp-amplification-ddos-attack/

and here :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Reflected_.2F_spoofed_attack

PS, this is illegal (in some territories), so watch out!

Comment: Assuming you don't own a network time server, I would think that using one for a purpose it wasn't built for would be looked upon unfavorably by whomever owns the time server you are running an attack with. If they don't want you to do it, but you do it anyway, chances are they could have you prosecuted if they can identify you.

To be prosecuted, you have to be doing something illegal.

Common sense really.

more to the point, a DDOS attack most likely is malicious.

I doubt you could get away with the "I was just stress testing" argument if you are not using your own equipment.